# Hibernate update before insert in one to many

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am getting the constraint violation exception because of the order of operations performed by Hibernate. I have the following entities defined.

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<B> bList;

    public void setBList(List<B> bList) {

        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(this.bList)) {
            this.bList.clear();
        }

        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(bList)) {
            this.bList.addAll(bList);
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "a_id", "isDeleted"})})
public class B {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="a_id")
    private A a;

    private boolean isDeleted;
}
```

When I set the new list of Bs (containing one item updated as deleted and a new item having the same values in the columns corresponding to constraint) in entity A and save entity A, I get constraint violation.

Hibernate is performing insert of the new item before updating the old item as deleted leading to constraint violation when in fact the data is correct in the application.

Am I doing something wrong here or Is there any configuration or fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

*Answer changed on 2021/05/07 due to comment from the OP pointing out it was missing the point*

There are 2 things you should change for things to work

1. You should not rely on Hibernate to guess the right order of operations for you. It relies on heuristics that might not fit your intent. In your case, you should call `EntityManager.flush` after your soft-delete of the old `B` and before persisting the new one.
2. Your unique constrain will cause problems anyway, when you'll soft-delete your second `B`, that is identical regarding unique columns. *More hereafter*

In general, ensuring this kind of constrains in DB is a bad idea. If you try and update/insert an entity that violates them, then you'll get an obscure `PersistenceException` and it will be hard to warn your users about the exact cause. So you will have to programmatically check those constrains before insertion/update anyways. Hence, you'd better remove them and ensure unicity through your program, unless they're vital to data integrity. Same goes for not-nullable columns and other constrains that are pure business logic.

Now last advice from experience: for soft-delete column, use a `TimeStamp` rather than a `boolean`. Same effort updating and reading your records, but it gives you some valuable information about when a record was deleted.

Comment: Each entry in `bList` parameter of `setBList` setter already has the reference of A set. I don't think that is the problem I am facing here.

Comment: Sorry I had read your post a little to fast and missed the point. I still have things to say. So I'm changing my answer completely